# php multiple file uploads get the exact count of files a user uploaded and not the count of all input fields in the array

Tags: php, file-upload

Ok. I give up on this. When uploading multiple files to the server using php, what is a fail safe method to return the count of files the user has actually uploaded?

Whatever I have done so far, returns the count of all the fields in the form, and the count of the files a user uploads. So if the total fields in the form were 3 and a user uploaded only 2 files, I still get 3 as the count of file uploaded.

One place suggested using `array_filter` to do this, but that's totally beyond me.

```
echo count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); //3

echo count($_FILES['file']); //3
```

Any fail safe method you follow and can suggest other than looping through the `FILES` array `size` to check for this?

My form is structured like any other:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div><input type="file" name="file[]"></div>
<div><input type="file" name="file[]"></div>
<div><input type="file" name="file[]"></div>
<div><input type="submit"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: It will give 3 only as you have 3 file tag. You need to check "tmp_name" to confirm how many are uploaded.

Comment: Why would you not want to loop through the array – don’t you have to do that anyway to _process_ the uploaded files …?

Comment: `tmp_name` also give me 3. See my question.

Comment: @CBroe My idea is to check if user / hacker managed to send more files that that. So if count >3 {die()); It's easy to do this using dev tools.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exactly as they told you, just simply use array_filter().

```
echo count(array_filter($_FILES['file']['name']));
```

It will return the right number

Comment: Still returns count as 3.

Comment: And are you sure, you're not uploading three files? And that you are using $_POST as I do, not $_FILES?

Comment: Using `_POST` gives `Notice: Undefined index: file`

Comment: Can you send me the whole form html? Are you using post method, right?

Comment: I wonder who down-voted this, and why... It worked this time. Wonder if this has any loop holes / gotchas however.

Comment: Array filter without the second parameter just removes empty values (null, false, empty string, zero, empty array...). Will you accept the answer if it worked?

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;
foreach($_FILES as $file) {
    if(isset($file["file"]["tmp_name"]) && !empty($file["file"]["tmp_name"]))
        $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$count = 0;
$fileCount=count($_FILE['file']['name'];)
$fileSize=$_FILES['file']['size'];

    for($i=0;$i<$ fileCount;$i++) {
        if ($fileSize[$i] > 0) {
           $count++;
        }
    }
```