# how to count number of uploaded files in php

Tags: php, count

How can i count the number of uploaded files?
This is my form:

```
<div id="dragAndDropFiles" class="uploadArea">
        <h1>Drop Images Here</h1>
    </div>
    <form id="sfmFiler" class="sfmform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple />
        <input type="submit" name="submitHandler" id="submitHandler" class="buttonUpload" value="Upload">
    </form>
```

and this is the piece of php which uploads the files:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $newFilePath = $dir.'/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
      echo "xxx files are successfully uploaded";
    }
}
```

Comment: try this: `count($_FILES['file']['name'])`

Comment: `echo count($_FILES);`

Comment: @Saty this also is gives me always number 1

Comment: Need array in  file name as `name="file[]"`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this code you are getting only one file thats why you are getting count result 1. if change your input file name like "file[]"

```
  <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple />
```

and then use the below line code you will get your desire result. Cause its needs an array filed to hold the input data.

```
 <?php echo count($_FILES['file']['name']); ?>
```

Thanks, i tried in my system get the result.

Comment: I could be wrong on this but count will always be 1 or greater unless the the paramter is NULL, so even if no files were uploaded count() would still equal 1

Answer (score 10):

AFriend is correct. The above answers always return 1.

Try:

```
echo count(array_filter($_FILES['file']['name']))
```

Worked for me anyway.

_t

Answer (score 3):

Using the `array_filter` function it works

try

```
$countfiles = count(array_filter($_FILES['file']['name']));
```

It returns 0 in case of NULL, 1 in case of 1 file uploaded, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer

```
<?php echo count($_FILES['file']['name']); ?>
```

[php multiple file uploads get the exact count of files a user uploaded and not the count of all input fields in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423954/php-multiple-file-uploads-get-the-exact-count-of-files-a-user-uploaded-and-not-t)

Comment: if you answer than make it clear. the op needs complete support. carry on.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `count` function:

```php
$no_files = count($_FILES);
```

Answer (score 0):

If no files are selected and your file count is 1, you can use this line before moving the file:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][0])) { 
    for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
```