# How to get multiple file count using PHP

Tags: php, html, multiple-file-upload

I want to get multiple files count. But i'm taking error. My error;

```
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

this my HTML code

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="fileImage" name="fileImage"
                             class="custom-file-image-input"
                             accept="image/*"
                             multiple="multiple">
        <input type="submit" value="OK" name="send">

</form>
```

this my PHP code

```
if($_POST['send'])
{
    print $c = count($_FILES['fileImage']['name']);
}
```

if i do `'count($_FILES['fileImage']);'` // Response => 5 this wrong.

when i delete a image, i'm taking wrong count.

this my js code

```
this.element.parent().on('click', '.custom-file-preview-del', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let del = $(this);
        let id = del.data('key');
        let index = ref.imageFileArray.findIndex(item => {
            return item.index == id;
        });
        ref.imageFileArray.splice(index, 1);
        del.parent().remove();
        //Array after deleted
        console.log(ref.imageFileArray);
    });
```

when i see on console screen, delete process is true.

I need help. Thanks regards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to count number of uploaded files in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363231/how-to-count-number-of-uploaded-files-in-php)

Comment: i know this, but if i put '[ ]', when i delete a image, i'm taking wrong number

Answer (score 0):

I imagine in this instance, you only have one file uploaded.

The first you'd want to do is make sure that multiple files can be submitted by changing the name of your input, at the moment you have `name="fileImage"`, this would only allow one file to be submitted, you need to change the name so that it can contain multiple values, like so:

```
<input type="file" name="fileImage[]"
```

If there is one file, `name` will be a string, if there are multiple it would be an array, so the thing to do would be to first check whether or not it is an array before deciding whether or not to count it.

```
if($_POST['send'])
{
    $c = (is_array($_FILES['fileImage']['name']) ? count($_FILES['fileImage']['name']) : 1);
    print $c;
}
```

[Output when multiple files are uploaded.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Comment: i know this, but if i put '[ ]', when i delete a image, i'm taking wrong count. how can i do?

Comment: You need to elaborate - edit your question and post more of your code and explain this delete issue some more.