# How to know if file is selected or not if we use multiple in html tag

Tags: php

I want to check on form submit. User is selected a file not not if files are multiple

Here is html code

```
 <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file[]"  accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.pdf"  multiple />
```

Here is php code

```
$file_upload=!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
        print_r($file_upload);die();
```

This work fine if select dropdown is not multiple. if dropdown is multiple then it always return true. I also use it with `$_FILE['file[]']` but it not working.

Comment: `count($_FILES['file']['name'])`; It will return you how many files had been uploaded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php multiple file uploads get the exact count of files a user uploaded and not the count of all input fields in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423954/php-multiple-file-uploads-get-the-exact-count-of-files-a-user-uploaded-and-not-t)

Answer (score 0):

Loop thru and check each file..

```
// check and see whether is empty
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && count($_FILES['file']['name']) > 0){
     foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $val){
           // some code here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you load the contents of the file? And why store it in a variable called `$filename`? You're also missing the closing `)` for `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Well, I thought, it would be good to do an additional check for content on whether its empty or not.. completely optional.

Comment: That seems very unnecessary. Just check if `tmp_name` is empty or not or just check the file size. If they are OK, you should be set. If there are multiple semi big files, this is just a performance loss.

Comment: if we select 2 files then count return 2 if we select one file then count return 1 and if we do not select any file then it also returns 1 because it returns this Array ( [0] => ). so problem not solved

Comment: You can do `array_filter()` and `count()`.. Example `count(array_filter($_FILES['file']['name']))`;

Answer (score 0):

if you've defined your input name as `file[]`, your $_FILES array would always contain an array. No matter single or multiple files are selected, the structure would be:

```
$_FILES['file']['name'][0] => first file name
$_FILES['file']['size'][0] => first file size
// if you've filled two inputs
$_FILES['file']['name'][1] => second file name
$_FILES['file']['size'][1] => second file size
```